# Flutter ble read weight scale characteristic value

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to flutter, i'm trying to connect to A&D ble weight scale and fetch the weight data, from the service 00002a9d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb i get the value [1, 48, 22] i'm using flutter_blue library, the weight value is 56.8 lb, how do i convert it to array value to actual weight value.TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/weight-scale-service/) for the weight service 0x2A98 shows you the different fields of the service and characteristics.

> Included in the characteristic value are a Flags field (for showing the presence of
> optional fields and measurement units), a Weight field, and depending upon the
> contents of the Flags field, may include one or more optional fields defined in 2.

Chapter 3.2 describes the fields:

1. Flags Field
2. Weight Field
3. Time Stamp Field (optional)
4. User ID Field (included if flag is set)
5. BMI and Height Field Pair (included if flag is set)

Based on this information we can assume that your received 3 bytes are the flags field and the weight field.

The flag field is set to 1 or `0x01` in hex which means that only the first bit is set. The first bit, according to the documentation, describes the measurement unit. A value of 1 shows that the measurement unit is set to imperial.

The second and third byte you received contain the weight as a uint16 split up into two bytes. We have to figure out the byte order (endianness) of the value. We can do this using a [hex to integer converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html):

The two values you received (48 and 22) can be represented as `0x30` and `0x16` in hex. Depending on which value comes first we get different values if we merge them together:

`0x3016` -> 12310
`0x1630` -> 5680

Since you measured a weight of 56.8 lb  we now know that the order `0x1630` represents the correct value with two digits after the decimal point.

You can extract the correct value from your List like this:

```dart
void main() {
  List<int> received = [1,48,22];
  // Get the weight value from the list starting at index 1
  print(getWeight(received, 1));
}

double getWeight(List<int> data, index) {
  return (( 0xff & data[index + 1] ) << 8 | ( 0xff & data[index] ) << 0 ) / 100;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is Exactly what i was looking, Thanks for taking time for explaining in detail with the links :)