# React Native Mi Scale Weight Data

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, scale, react-native-ble-plx, mi

I am trying to getting data from mi scale V2. I am getting service data like this: “serviceData”: {“0000181b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb”: “BiTlBwcZFgsYAAAmAg==”}(5.15kg) and I decode the base64 string to array like this [66, 105, 84, 108, 66, 119, 99, 90, 70, 103, 115, 89, 65, 65, 65, 109, 65, 103, 61, 61] But I can not retrieve the correct result. How can I get  the weight data?

Answer (score 0):

The UUID `0000181b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` belongs to the pre-defined Body Composition Service (BCS). You can download the specification from [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/body-composition-service-1-0/).

It should have the two characteristics *Body Composition Feature* and *Body Composition Measurement*.

The *Features* characteristic shows you the features supported by your scale, the measurement characteristic returns the actual measurement.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68233478/flutter-ble-read-weight-scale-characteristic-value/68251225#68251225) answer where I explain the process of decoding a sample weight measurement.

Answer (score 0):

UUIDs with the format of `0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` are an officially adopted Bluetooth SIG UUID and can be looked up online.

If you look at the following URL:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/
there is a document with the title "16-bit UUIDs". I can see from that document that `0x181b` is Body Composition GATT Service.

According to the "Body Composition Service 1.0" document at:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/
there should be a Body Composition Feature (0x2A9B) and a Body Composition Measurement (0x2A9C) characteristic available for that service.

It will be the Body Composition Measurement characteristic that will contain the weight value.

A generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) can be useful when exploring and understanding the data on a device.

Comment: Thanks you for responding and taking time. I Have downloaded the nRF Connect  mobile and I looked the data from the scale. nRF I found the uuid:0x2A9C  body composition measurement but when I logged the terminal data getting from my app. I can not see any hexadecimal number.

Comment: What do you see when reading the characteristic using nRF Connect?

Comment: The Body Composition Measurement characteristic has a flag of `Indicate` so you are probably not be able to "read" the value. You will need to enable `notifications` (which is done by clicking on the multiple-down-arrows icon against the characteristic in nRF Connect)

Comment: When the icons on the right are missing, it normally means the device is disconnected.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, sorry for this. I uploaded the new one here: https://imgur.com/2shVS3F

Comment: What happens if you click on the up-down-arrows next to `0x2A9C`? Do you get some data sent?