# Get weighments from Bluetooth Weigh Scale Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a bluetooth weigh scale and am i want to read weighments in kgs using flutter (flutter_blue). I have got the services, and the specific characteristic with the weighments (0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb). However the data is returned as a List. Forexample [2,66,32,32,32,32,48,46,57,217,13].

How do i convert this to kgs?

Scale Type:OCS Crane Scale 500kg with Bluetooth

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The UUID 0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is a proprietary implementation within the Bluetooth LE standard.  Without documentation from the manufacturer you will need to reverse engineer how data in this PDU has to be interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

As Risto already wrote in the comments, the UUID you provided is not the standard UUID for the Weight Scale Service. But the data structure you received had me thinking. I explained the process of converting data from the Weight Scale Service in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68233478/flutter-ble-read-weight-scale-characteristic-value/68251225#68251225) and your dataset might still be according to the standard.

As described in the standard, the first byte is the flags field and a value of 2 means that the first bit is not set (measurement in Kilogram) and the second bit is set. The second bit means that the timestamp of your measurement is present which would explain the amount of data you are getting.

The actual measured weight can be found in the second and third Bytes according to the standard. If I apply the same calculation as I explained in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68233478/flutter-ble-read-weight-scale-characteristic-value/68251225#68251225) on this topic I get a weight of 82.58kg. If that actually is the weight you put on the scale the characteristic you are reading returns the weight according to the Bluetooth standard (or we found a really nice coincidence).